# Is it possible to drag an image within canvas as well as draw on the same canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here I'm trying to draw on a html5 canvas as well as upload some images and drag them within the canvas. The problem is I can do one or the other but not both. 
What I've realised is that the canvas must be Cleared before dragging takes place but by doing that I'm clearing the drawing and if I don't clear the canvas it draws but dragging an image leaves trail behind. Can anyone point me to right direction please.

```
        function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
        img = document.getElementById("drag");

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) { findxy('move', e) }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) { findxy('down', e) }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {  findxy('up', e) }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) { findxy('out', e) }, false);

        imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
        imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

        var contexts = [];
        contexts.push(canvas.getContext('2d'));

        function clearAll() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

       canvas.onclick = function (e) { handleClick(e, 1); };

        function handleClick(e, contextIndex) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
            var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);
        //    clearAll();
            for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

                var state = states[i];
                if (state.dragging) {
                    state.dragging = false;
                    state.draw();
                    continue;
                }

                if (state.contextIndex === contextIndex
                        && mouseX > state.x && mouseX < state.x + state.width
                        && mouseY > state.y && mouseY < state.y + state.height)
                {
                    state.dragging = true;
                    state.offsetX = mouseX - state.x;
                    state.offsetY = mouseY - state.y;
                    state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
                }
                state.draw();
            }
        }
        canvas.onmousemove = function (e) { handleMousemove(e, 1); }

        function handleMousemove(e, contextIndex) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
            var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);

        //    clearAll();

            for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {

                var state = states[i];

                if (state.dragging) {
                    state.x = mouseX - state.offsetX;
                    state.y = mouseY - state.offsetY;
                    state.contextIndex = contextIndex;
                }
                state.draw();
            }
        }
       var states = [];
        states.push(addState(0, 0, img));

        function addState(x, y, image) {
            state = {}
            state.dragging = false;
            state.contextIndex = 1;
            state.image = image;
            state.x = x;
            state.y = y;
            state.width = image.width;
            state.height = image.height;
            state.offsetX = 0;
            state.offsetY = 0;
            state.draw = function () {
                var context = contexts[this.contextIndex - 1];
                if (this.dragging) {
                    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
                    context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width + 5, this.height + 5);
                }
                context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
            };
            state.draw();
            return(state);
        }

}//end of init()  

var imgArray = [];
function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        imgArray.push(img);
        for(i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++){
            img.src = imgArray[i];
            img.setAtX = i * 50;
            img.setAtY = i * 0;
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(this, this.setAtX, this.setAtY);
            };
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);                
}
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res === 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res === 'up' || res === "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res === 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }

    //Draw lines or text 
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();           
        ctx.fillStyle = x;           
        ctx.font = "Italic Bold 14pt Times, serif";            
        ctx.fillText(message, prevX, prevY);
    }
```

Comment: http://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really help me because I'm drawing on canvas as well as dragging images.

Comment: drawing on a canvas is fast, so clear and redraw everything. Keep all in objects so that it's easier to redraw. You'll then be able to add a lot of features on your canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final code that's working , I had to add two canvases one for the drawing and one for the dragging images. Fabric frame work helped a lot. https://jsfiddle.net/tn07Bond/982s4bgv/2/

```
<div id="canvasesdiv">
        <canvas id="images" width=600 height=400 style="position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            z-index: 1;">
            This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
        <canvas id="drawing" width=600 height=400 style="position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            border: 1px solid red;
            z-index: 2;">
            This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>

        <input type="file" id="imageLoader" class="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/> 

        <input type="image" src="images/PenForCanvas.png" alt="pen" title="Draw on canvas" 
               id="Drawing" style="cursor: pointer; margin: 5px 0 0 200px;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="image" src="images/drag.png" alt="drag" title="Drag this image"  id="Images" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </div>


    <script>

        var drawing, drawingCtx,images,imagesCtx, message = "", img, imageLoader, prevX = 10, currX = 10, prevY = 10, currY = 10,
                dot_flag = false, flag = false, x = "black", y = 2, formElement, canvasLeft, canvasTop, imgData, data,
                startOffsetX = 0, startOffsetY = 0;

(function () {

        // Drawing canvas
        drawing = document.getElementById("drawing");
        drawingCtx = drawing.getContext("2d");

        //Uploading and dragging images
        images = new fabric.Canvas('images');
        document.getElementById('imageLoader').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
          var file = e.target.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (f) {
            var data = f.target.result;                    
            fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
              var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:40, height:40}).scale(0.9);
              images.add(oImg).renderAll();
              var a = images.setActiveObject(oImg);
              var dataURL = images.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
            });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

            w = drawing.width;
            h = drawing.height;

            //Mouse events
            drawing.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) { findxy('move', e) }, false);
            drawing.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) { findxy('down', e) }, false);
            drawing.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) { findxy('up', e) }, false);
            drawing.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) { findxy('out', e) }, false);

            Drawing = document.getElementById("Drawing");
            Drawing.addEventListener("click", bringDrawingToFront);
            Images = document.getElementById("Images");
            Images.addEventListener("click", bringImagesToFront);
            imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
            imageLoader.addEventListener('change', bringImagesToFront);

        //Drawing
        function findxy(res, e) {
            if (res === 'down') {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - drawing.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - drawing.offsetTop;

                flag = true;
                dot_flag = true;
                if (dot_flag) {
                    drawingCtx.beginPath();
                    drawingCtx.fillStyle = x;
                    drawingCtx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                    drawingCtx.closePath();
                    dot_flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (res === 'up' || res === "out") {
                flag = false;
            }
            if (res === 'move') {
                if (flag) {
                    prevX = currX;
                    prevY = currY;
                    currX = e.clientX - drawing.offsetLeft;
                    currY = e.clientY - drawing.offsetTop;
                    draw();
                }
            }
        }

        function save() {
            imgData = drawingCtx.getImageData(0, 0, drawing.width, drawing.height);
        }

        function restore() {
            drawingCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
        }
        function bringDrawingToFront() {
            drawing.style.zIndex = 1;
            document.getElementById("images").style.zIndex = 0;
        }
        function bringImagesToFront() {
            drawing.style.zIndex = 0;
            document.getElementById("images").style.zIndex = 1;
        }

        //Draw lines or text 
        function draw() {
            drawingCtx.beginPath();
            drawingCtx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
            drawingCtx.lineTo(currX, currY);
            drawingCtx.strokeStyle = x;
            drawingCtx.lineWidth = y;
            drawingCtx.stroke();
            drawingCtx.closePath();
            drawingCtx.fillStyle = x;
            drawingCtx.font = "Italic Bold 14pt Times, serif";
            drawingCtx.fillText(message, prevX, prevY);
            save();
        }

})();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mashup of the code i linked to and your own.

All parameters related to drawing the image and translating it around the canvas is covered.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx;
var x = 75;
var y = 50;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300;
var dragok = false;
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var lines = [{
  x: x,
  y: y
}];

function rect(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  return setInterval(draw, 1000/24);
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  ctx.drawImage(img, x - img.width / 2, y - img.height / 2);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lines[0].x,lines[0].y);
  for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    ctx.lineTo(lines[i].x,lines[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke(); 
  ctx.closePath();
  //rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
}

function myMove(e) {
  if (dragok) {
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    lines = lines.slice(lines.length - 100)
    lines.push({
      x: x,
      y: y
    });
  }
}

function myDown(e) {
  if (e.pageX < x + img.width / 2 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - img.width / 2 +
    canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + img.height / 2 + canvas.offsetTop &&
    e.pageY > y - img.height / 2 + canvas.offsetTop) {
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    dragok = true;
    canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
  }
}

function myUp() {
  dragok = false;
  canvas.onmousemove = null;
}

init();

canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
canvas.onmouseup = myUp;

//Change image for the heck of it ^^

setInterval(function() {
  img.src = 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=' +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +
    '&w=100&h=100';
}, 3000)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
<img id="img" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=1&w=100&h=100">
```

**Updated my answer to draw lines**

Comment: Thanks again, now try to draw a line on the same canvas where you're dragging the image.

Comment: I'm trying to take some ideas from you if it works I'll mark you as an answer but at the moment it's drawing on image when you start to drag it.

Comment: @wasn't that where you wanted the trail? If you want it to go behind the image, simply change the draw order in the `draw` function, so the image goes on top of the trail.

Comment: No, What I was saying when I'm dragging an Image in my code it leaves trail behind which I didn't want I have to run 'Clean()' before I can smoothly drag image but by doing that I'm clearing all the drawing that I had done. I'm still looking at your code though ...

Comment: This is how far I'm getting which is not much further than I was before https://jsfiddle.net/tn07Bond/jsf1t6gn/11/

Comment: A bit of an improvement, now the image leaves a copy of it self before being dragged after drawing. https://jsfiddle.net/jsf1t6gn/13/

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how I can drag every uploaded image ? At the moment I can only drag the last one rest become part of background image. I know I need to instantiate each image but It doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/tn07Bond/jsf1t6gn/21/

Comment: Can anyone give me some input on this please :-(